# Entry level jobs on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Why does [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) list only senior developers or experienced persons? Where can I find jobs for entry level developers or freshers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Presumably because that's what the employers using SO Careers are looking for. Maybe you will have to look elsewhere for entry-level roles.

Comment: Advertising jobs costs money, that's how SE makes a living.  Companies are less inclined to spend such money on entry-level positions.  They usually work with interns or get a referral from a local school or work through a stack of resumes sent to them unsolicited.  If you don't have the intern/school angle then just send out your resume to any company that looks like a good place to work.  The more you send, the likelier you'll get a call back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, entry-level jobs tend to be less frequent. But they do exist and, depending on your other search criteria (geography, technologies...), you might be able to find quite a few of them on our job board.

Try customizing the "matches" tab on the job search page to find them more easily - click that little gear to edit your job matches:

[image]

In the seniority section on the match preferences page, add *junior* (and, if applicable, *student*):

[image]

Your job matches should now be skewed towards mostly entry-level jobs.